# table for two pages in single column format

Tags: tables

I want to create a two page table in single column document format  but I m failed to do so. I have already used "longtable" and "supertabular" usepackages but no result please suggest me how can I create a table for more than one page ??

**edit:**

below is code which op provide in her/his comment:

```
\begin{table*}[!p] 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9} 
\caption{Classification } 
     \label{Comparison} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|} 
   \hline 
\bfseries Sensor Type & \bfseries Sensing Approach & \bfseries Deliverables & \bfseries Reference\\ 
    \hline 
PIR & Conventional & Energy saving, & \\ \hline CO2 &Conventional& Electricity forecast estimation& \\ 
    \hline 
Camera & Conventional & Building energy management, & \\ 
    \hline 
Ultrasonic & Conventional & Head count, person identification, presence detection& \\ 
     \hline 
 \end{tabular} 
 \end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post the code you've tried. It should have worked, so there must be some syntax errors.

Comment: \begin{table*}[!p]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\caption{Classification }
\label{Comparison}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|p{2.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\bfseries  & \bfseries  & \bfseries  & \bfseries \\
\hline
&   & \\
\hline
& & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

Comment: Please add  the code to your question, and provide a full compilable code, not just a fragment.

Comment: \begin{table*}[!p]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\caption{Classification }
\label{Comparison}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|p{2.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\bfseries Sensor Type & \bfseries Sensing Approach & \bfseries Deliverables & \bfseries Reference\\
\hline
PIR & Conventional & Energy saving, & \\
\hline
CO2 &Conventional& Electricity forecast estimation& \\
\hline
Camera&Conventional& Building energy management, & \\
\hline
Ultrasonic&Conventional& Head count, person identification, presence detection& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

Comment: This is always a fragment. It should begin with `\documentclass`, load the relevant package(s) you need  and end with `\end{document}`. Furthermore, you can edit your question to add the code.

Comment: @user824, your table (i) seems to be to wide for fit in one column (ii) for `longtable` you need to change `twocolumn`˙option to `onecolumn` which always start new page (ii) as you indicate in code sniped, use of `table*` is possible solution if you manually split table into two parts which follows each other (in this package `stfloats` can be handy)

Answer (score 0):

As per the posted code, understood that you didn't try with the standard coding format either `longtable` or `supertabular`. Please follow as per the documentation for those package and still if you have any issues, please post your `MWE` for the same...

Comment: this answer is rather comment ...

Answer (score 0):

let me elaborate my above comment. as possible solution seems to be manual split table in two parts and use packages `caption` for `\ContinuedFloat` and `stfloat` for placing first table an the bottom of the same page (if this is necessary). for example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Classification}
\label{Comparison}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} p{2cm} p{6cm} p{4cm} }
   \toprule
\thead[b]{Sensor\\ Type}
    &   \thead[b]{Sensing\\ Approach}
        &   \thead[b]{Deliverables}
            &   \thead[b]{Reference}        \\
    \midrule
PIR &   Conventional    & \lipsum*[11]  &   \\
    \addlinespace
CO2 &   Conventional    & \lipsum*[11]  &   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\begin{table*}[t]
\ContinuedFloat,
\caption{Classification (cont.)}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} p{2cm} p{6cm} p{4cm} }
   \toprule
\thead[b]{Sensor\\ Type}
    &   \thead[b]{Sensing\\ Approach}
        &   \thead[b]{Deliverables}
            &   \thead[b]{Reference}            \\
    \midrule
Camera      & Conventional  & \lipsum*[11] &    \\
    \addlinespace
Ultrasonic  & Conventional  & \lipsum*[11] &    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

where `lipsum` is used for simulate longer table with dummy text in cells. this gives:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Classification}
\label{Comparison}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} p{2cm} p{6cm} p{4cm} }
   \toprule
\thead[b]{Sensor\\ Type}
    &   \thead[b]{Sensing\\ Approach}
        &   \thead[b]{Deliverables}
            &   \thead[b]{Reference}        \\
    \midrule
PIR &   Conventional    & \lipsum*[11]  &   \\
    \addlinespace
CO2 &   Conventional    & \lipsum*[11]  &   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\begin{table*}[t]
\ContinuedFloat,
\caption{Classification (cont.)}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} p{2cm} p{6cm} p{4cm} }
   \toprule
\thead[b]{Sensor\\ Type}
    &   \thead[b]{Sensing\\ Approach}
        &   \thead[b]{Deliverables}
            &   \thead[b]{Reference}            \\
    \midrule
Camera      & Conventional  & \lipsum*[11] &    \\
    \addlinespace
Ultrasonic  & Conventional  & \lipsum*[11] &    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

note: red lines only show page layout. in real document you should remove package `showframe`.